# Estimate the $x$-coordinate of the point where $g''(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

[image]

I know the only point where $g''(x)=0$ will occur when the line turns into a straight line. How do I find where that happens without an equation of the line and just a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look for where the concavity changes (in this case, where does the graph stop being concave down and begins to be concave up?). When $g''(x_0)=0$, $x_0$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are looking at the graph of $g(x)$ here, NOT the graph of $g''(x)$ so I will continue my answer based off of that assumption.

When it comes to the graph of any continuous function $g(x)$, we are able to make estimates about $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$, the first and second derivatives of $g$ with respect to $x$, even without an equation.

The graphical meaning of the first derivative $g'(x)$ talks about the **slope** of the original function $g(x)$. When $g'(x) = 0$, then the original graph, the graph of $g(x)$, will be changing direction from increasing to decreasing. For this particular case, see that the graph is always increasing, so there is no $x$ such that $g'(x) = 0$

The second derivative $g''(x)$ talks about the **[concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Concavity)** of the original graph. That is, does the graph look like it is opened up or opened down? A very simple example would be to look at $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$. The first equation is an example of positive concavity and the second example is one for negative concavity. A third example, $y=x^3$, includes both, as it has positive concavity to the right of $x=0$ and negative concavity to the left of $x=0$. For this specific example, $x=0$ is what is known as a [inflection point.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)

Getting back to your example, try and see where the graph starts going from being opened down (concave down) to being opened up (concave up). At that particular value of $x$ is where $g''(x) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You graphed the cubic

$$ y= (x-3)(x^2+3x +32)/48 \tag1 $$

passing through

$$(0,2),(-3,-4),(5,3) $$

When above points are plugged into a quadratic of unknown coefficients you get (1).

Now successive derivatives are

$$ y^{'}= (3x^2+23)/48$$

$$ y^{''}=\frac{x}{8}$$

When above second derivative vanishes, i.e., when (here cubic) a curve is locally straight you have an inflection point always. In this case

$$ (x=0, y=-2 ) $$

is the inflection point on y-axis in your plot/graph.